# Extract query parts from a SelectQuery (or equivalents)?

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq, sqlbuilder

I have the following situation:

Class `A extends B`. Other classes, such as `C`, `D`, etc. also extend `B` In Class `B`, I would like to situate logic with regard to general information common to `A`, `C`, and `D`.

Hence, I would like to have a general query in `B` that retrieves all general info, but also be able to pass a `Query` to `B` so that the correct `join`s and `condition`s are fulfilled. Basically:

```
public B getB(String bUuid, Query extendedQuery) {

    SelectQuery bQuery = ... dsl.select(/* general B columns */)
                                .select(/* SELECT part from extended query */)
                                .from(/* general B tables */)
                                .from(/* FROM part from extended query */) // maybe join with some if else logic instead 
                                .where(/* general B conditions */)
                                .where(/* WHERE part of extended query */)
```

Is this possible using JOOQ? I would really not like to use plain SQL execution unless absolutely necessary.

---

EDIT:

Using the below answer, this is the final code I have that I am quite satisfied with:

```
public Record getB(String bUuid, Consumer<SelectQuery> extender)
```

Which I call as follows:

```
Record r = B.getB(uuid, query -> {
    query.addSelect(...);
    query.addJoin(...);
}
```

And in getB, after making our "general" `SelectQuery query`, we simply call:

```
extender.apply(query);
```

Afterwards we can simply do `query.fetchOne()` with our enhanced query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think functional, not object oriented! This would be a much simpler approach:

```java
public B getB(
    String bUuid,
    Supplier<? extends Collection<? extends Field<?>>> select,
    Supplier<? extends Collection<? extends Table<?>>> from,
    Supplier<? extends Collection<? extends Condition>> where
) {
    List<Field<?>> allSelect = new ArrayList<>();
    allSelect.addAll(/* general B columns */);
    allSelect.addAll(select.get());

    List<Table<?>> allFrom = new ArrayList<>();
    allFrom.addAll(/* general B tables */);
    allFrom.addAll(from.get());

    List<Table<?>> allWhere = new ArrayList<>();
    allWhere.addAll(/* general B conditions*/);
    allWhere.addAll(where.get());

    dsl.select(allSelect)
       .from(allFrom)
       .where(allWhere);
}
```

Now, you can call this higher-order function like so:

```java
getB(
    uuid,
    () -> Arrays.asList(A.COL1, A.COL2, A.COL3),
    () -> Arrays.asList(A),
    () -> Arrays.asList(A.B_ID.eq(B.ID), A.COL4.like("%ABC%"))
);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply Mr. Eder! Using your suggestion as a basis, I went with the solution that I edited into my question above. I also highly appreciate you taking the time to answer questions here on SO. :)

Comment: @user991710: You're welcome! Oh, interesting approach, using the consumer. Note: You can also answer your own questions here on Stack Overflow. That will make it even a more interesting question for future visitors